# How to introduce and make less variables in SCSS

Tags: css, variables, sass

I have a lot of color variables on SCSS and HTML. Each color corresponds with an HTML page and I need to color elements and text. Anyone how to do it without creating a lot of classes or styles?

Example:

`$color-linea1: rgba(58,167,226);` corresponds with elements in metro-linea1.html

`$color-linea2: rgba(196,29,39);` corresponds with elements in metro-linea2.html

`$color-linea3: rgba(250,212,60);` corresponds with elements in metro-linea3.html

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to explain the problem better. It stands to reason that each color needs a class or variable (or both). I'm not sure how you'd avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

Your variables should [correspond with colors](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/tutorials/scss-color-variables/), not with pages. Name your variable after the color value it contains, and then use that variable in your style rules. If you need different pages to have different colors, then create  page-specific **style rules**, not page-specific **variables**.